# Creating Excel-formatted XML

Tags: xml, excel

I have an application which users use to enter and save data in files. Each file may then have its data exported to XML. So far so good; the XML is generated without problems.

This XML data then needs to be viewed in Excel. If the XML file is opened directly, though, the formatting of the data in Excel is less than ideal - columns not in order, for instance.

With Excel I can create a mapping which neatly displays the XML data. However, I have to specify a particular data source for the Excel file. It therefore isn't very useful for all the other XML files, although they are identical in structure.

I can refresh the data source to update it from the XML file, or I can change the data source, but this still requires opening the Excel file first, then altering the data source. It's a lot more trouble for my users than simply double-clicking the outputted file.

I was wondering if there was some way of specifiying in the XML file how to display the data in Excel, but this seems to me to violate the design-content-separation paradigm.

My aim is to provide a one-click method for them to output their data and then to open that data in Excel. Has anyone any ideas?

I suspect that XSL may be the answer, although I'm not clear how to go about using it.

Comment: What purpose does the xML serve - is it just for viewing in Excel?  If so, why not just output an Excel file instead?

Comment: The XML may be imported into Excel, or finally a Word document. The document has to be created and edited before the XML data is gathered, so the XML data can't be output into a new Excel/Word document directly. Good thought though.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to associate an XML schema (XSD file) to you Excel file, then save it. This would provide the user the possibility to export the file into a standardize and validated XML data.
You could follow this guide http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/using-xml-in-excel.php and then personalize the XSD file based on your needs.